# How can I create a s3 bucket subdirectory (Serverless)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, serverless

When I try to create a subdirectory on my `serverless.yml`, I get the following error:

```
An error occurred: S3Bucket - Bucket name should not contain '/'.
```

Here’s the code:

```
resources:
 Resources:
   S3Bucket:
     Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
     Properties:
       BucketName: "bucketname/sub"
```

How can I create bucket subdirectories through `serverless.yml`?

Comment: You typically do not need to create folders in S3, but if you really feel a need to do this at infrastructure build time then you might be able to do it via a custom resource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only create S3 bucket using serverless framework. Any folder/object can only be created using SDK or console.

Comment: that doesnt answer the question. He is asking how to make this work `BucketName: "bucketname/sub"
 `

Answer (score 2):

AWS S3 buckets don't have directories, they just appear to when a filename has a `/` in it.

See [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27009599/how-to-create-subdirectory-in-amazon-s3-bucket?rq=1)

Comment: I know, but the question is rather serverless specific. It does not accept `/` in bucket names, thus eliminating the possibility of creating subfolders.

Comment: Bucket names can't contain a slash. This is a limit from S3, not the serverless framework.